# how to create custom module for creating role programmatically in vtiger

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am new to Vtiger CRM and I have searched a lot to find how to create a custom module in Vtiger CRM for adding user role.

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger already provides a setting page to create a new role.
You can find it here
http://YOURVTIGERURL/index.php?module=Roles&parent=Settings&view=Index

obviously you have to replace YOURVTIGERURL with your root vtiger url.
You will find a + button when you will go on mouse over to the parent role you want to add a subrole.